# Delete rows based on FALSE value in Excel VBA (Runtime error 91)

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I have a spreadsheet that needs to have rows deleted based off a "FALSE" value. Researching the net, I found some code from this site:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/815-excel-remove-rows-based-on-cell-value.html

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim DeleteRng As Range
    Dim DeleteStr As String
    xTitleId = "Delete Based on Cell Value"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("Delete Text", xTitleId, Type:=2)
For Each rng In InputRng
If rng.Value = DeleteStr Then
    If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
        Set DeleteRng = rng
    Else
        Set DeleteRng = Application.Union(DeleteRng, rng)
    End If
End If
Next
DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete '<----- *highlighted error*

End Sub
```

Upon execution of the macro, I get the "Runtime 91 object variable not set" error.

I am aware that I need to set "DeleteRng" to an object, but I am not sure what. I am new to VBA and it could be something minor I am overlooking.

Comment: If DeleteRng is Nothing that means it isn't a Range object, you can't set it. Is that where your error is occurring?

Comment: What column in your worksheet contains the FALSE value?

Comment: Thank you for your responses! Column B contains "TRUE OR FALSE" values. I'm not sure if it makes a difference or not, but these values are based off an email validation function.

So in Column B I have =CheckEmail function, and it returns TRUE or FALSE. Does it make a difference if it is a string or function?

Comment: That could certainly do it depending on what the Range.Value is returning. You can force conversion to a string by doing "If CStr(rng.value) = DeleteStr then". If that doesn't work then your best bet is to step through your code and use the immediate window to find out what values are being returned.

Comment: I figured out my issue! I used your suggestion of using the immediate window to step through the code, and turns out I was making a minor mistake. The values are displayed in all caps in the spreadsheet, like "FALSE", but the value actually returns "False". I was typing "FALSE" in all caps, and that's why it didn't detect the value, so I typed "False" and it worked like a charm!

Thank you so much for your suggestion and help Brandon, and thank you for everyone that contributed! I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first that DeleteRng contains something

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim DeleteRng As Range
Dim DeleteStr As String
Dim xTitleId As String

xTitleId = "Delete Based on Cell Value"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
DeleteStr = Application.InputBox("Delete Text", xTitleId, Type:=2)

For Each rng In InputRng
    If rng.Value = DeleteStr Then
        If DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteRng = rng
        Else
            Set DeleteRng = Application.Union(DeleteRng, rng)
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not DeleteRng Is Nothing Then DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete '<----- *highlighted error*

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works just fine for me when I test it, but I have a feeling I know what is happening when you are running it. Chances are, it isnt finding the text you are inputting into your box.

Try putting a breakpoint at "DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete". You can do this by clicking in the thin grey bar of the window to the left of your code.

I would also edit your code from:

```
DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete '<----- *highlighted error*
```

to

```
If Not DeleteRng Is Nothing Then
    DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete '<----- *highlighted error*
Else
    msgbox "No rows found!"
End If
```

This will provide the inverse of your object. If the object is set to something, then the inverse is nothing. This will prevent your code from raising an error when an object isnt set. You can remove the else statement as well, but with the else statement in there it will tell you if nothing is set.

Comment: Hello Brandon, does it make a difference if the value is a string or function? The FALSE values are based off an email verification function, so could that be why the DeleteRows() macro doesn't find it?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I figured out my mistake! With a little help and modification to the code, as well as a suggestion, I realized that the value I was typing in was different from the returned value because it was case-sensitive.

Column B had the "FALSE" value displayed in all caps, but the immediate window showed the value was actually "False". I searched correctly with "False" and it worked perfectly!

I also changed the error part to:

```
If Not DeleteRng Is Nothing Then DeleteRng.EntireRow.Delete
```